# Something like Ctrp of Vim for Emacs?

Tags: search, plugins, emacs

I am looking for a tool or pluging that let me navigate across my files, directories and tags like Vim's Ctrlp but for Emacs, any suggestions?.

Comment: Would you mind better describing the functionality you seek for us that are unfamiliar with vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a Vim user, but after looking up CtrlP's functionality, it seems you are looking for `ido-mode`.

`ido-mode` comes with emacs and you can enable it by putting this in your .emacs

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)
```

There is a lot of features in `ido-mode` but this video is a good introduction to some basic functionality. Note the fuzzy matching is now enabled by default not in `ido-mode` but the video suggests you have to enable it yourself.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsgPNVIMkIE

For a complete reference, go here: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings

Comment: Thanks i will try that to see if it give me what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fipler](https://github.com/grizzl/fiplr) or use [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) with [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). It's the closest you can.

One problem with fipler is that if you have your home directory as a git repo(dotfiles) it just would take forever to get files when in home directory. Otherwise just go with fipler.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out textmate, and it's very cool :) ...

https://github.com/defunkt/textmate.el

It's provides pretty much the same, except the command is not "Ctrl+P", but it's "Command+T" ... (in my case - "Alt+T") ... :)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to accomplish this using the project-root-find-file helper function of project-root.el

Please see: http://solovyov.net/project-root/